# Como hacer para que no repita una pista y que me diga que ponga otra pista

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int compare(const void * a, const void * b) {
    if (*(int*)a <  *(int*)b) return -1;
    if (*(int*)a == *(int*)b) return 0;
    if (*(int*)a >  *(int*)b) return 1;
}


void shift(int a[], const int size) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
        a[i - 1] = a[i];
}

class disk {

public:
    int request[40];
    int number_of_request = 12;
    int sorted_request[12];
    int max = 40;
    int direction;
public:

    void receive_request() {
    current_location:
        cout << "Introduzca la posicion de inicio:\n";
        cin >> request[0];
        sorted_request[0] = request[0];
        if (request[0]>max || request[0]<0)
            goto current_location;

        cout << "\nIngrese las pistas:\n";
        for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_request; i++) {
            cin >> request[i];
            sorted_request[i] = request[i];
            if (request[i] == request[0]) {
                cout << "Pista no valida introdusca otra\n";
                i--;
            }
            if (request[i]>max || request[i]<0) {
                cout << "Pista no valida introdusca otra\n";
                i--;
            }
        }
        qsort(sorted_request + 1, number_of_request, sizeof(int), compare);

    }
    int SCAN() {
        int head_movement = 0, flag = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_request; i++) {
            if (sorted_request[i] > sorted_request[0] && flag == 0) {
                flag = i;
            }
        }
        if (flag == 1) {
            head_movement += sorted_request[number_of_request] - sorted_request[0];
        } else {
            head_movement += max - sorted_request[0];
            head_movement += max - sorted_request[1];
        }
        return head_movement;
    }
    ~disk() {}
};

int main() {
    disk hdd;
    hdd.receive_request();
    cout << "Movimientos totales  ";
    cout << hdd.SCAN() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <= hdd.number_of_request; i++) {
        if (hdd.sorted_request[i] == hdd.request[0]) continue;
        if (hdd.sorted_request[i] > hdd.request[0]) {
            cout << hdd.sorted_request[i];
            cout << "-->";
        }
    }
    for (int i = hdd.number_of_request; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        if (hdd.sorted_request[i] < hdd.request[0]) {
            cout << hdd.sorted_request[i];
            if (i - 1 == 0) {
                cout << endl;
            } else {
                cout << "-->";
            }
        }
    }
    _getche();
```

}[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: por favor, mira [ask]. cual es el lenguaje que estas usando?

Comment: El lenguaje que utilice es c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo estás comprobando si la pista actual es igual a la pista 0:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_request; i++) {
        cin >> request[i];
        sorted_request[i] = request[i];
        if (request[i] == request[0]) { // <<--- AQUI
            cout << "Pista no valida introdusca otra\n";
            i--;
        }
```

Si tu idea es evitar duplicados, tienes que comprobar TODAS las pistas:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_request; i++) {
        cin >> request[i];
        sorted_request[i] = request[i];
        bool ok = true;
        for( int j=0; j<i; j++ )
          ok &= (request[i] != request[j]);

        if (!ok)
        {
            cout << "Pista no valida introdusca otra\n";
            i--;
        }
```

Claro que para eso también puedes usar la stl:

```
    std::set<std::string> pistas;
    for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_request; i++) {
        cin >> request[i];
        sorted_request[i] = request[i];

        bool ok;
        std::tie(std::ignore,ok) = pistas.insert(request[i]);

        if (!ok)
        {
            cout << "Pista no valida introdusca otra\n";
            i--;
        }
```

`std::set` es un contenedor que **no admite duplicados**. Entonces, al insertar un elemento nuevo nos devolverá un par de valores:

- un iterador al elemento
- un booleano que indica si el elemento es nuevo (true) o si ya existía (false)

Lo que hacemos con la función `tie` es extraer el booleano e ignorar el iterador ya que no lo necesitamos (para eso usamos `std::ignore`).

El contenedor `set` no te sirve para guardar la lista de las pistas ya que este contenedor ordenará los elementos automáticamente y eso choca con el requisito de que las pistas mantengan el orden de inserción... en este caso `set` solo sirve como herramienta para evitar duplicados.

Answer (score 0):

tiene mucho que no programo en c++ así que te dejaré solamente algunos snippets:

Para empezar yo usaría una estructura de datos como set que no permita duplicados, y en dicho caso intentar insertar no sería exitoso y usamos el resultado para volver a pedir datos.

```
#include <set>
#include ...
using namespace std;

.
.
.
    set<int> mis_pistas;

   for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_request; i++) {
     int valor_leido;
     cin >> valor_leido;
     // mientras no se pueda guardar porque seguramente ya estaba
     while(!mis_pistas.insert(valor_leido)){
       cin >> valor_leido;
     }
```

Otra alternativa posible es que verifiques todo tu arreglo antes de insertar usando una bandera para no dejar pasar mientras la bandera de duplicidad esté activa:

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_request; i++) {
     int valor_leido;
     cin >> valor_leido;

     bool duplicado = false;
    while(duplicado){
      for (int j = 1; !duplicado && j <= number_of_request; j++) {
        if(request[j] == valor_leido ){
          duplicado=true;
          break;
        }
      }
      cin >> valor_leido;
    }
```